# oTable.fnGetNodes is not a function DataTable 1.10.13 server-side processing

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have used dataTable 1.7.6 and now changed it to 1.10
below function gives eror after updating version

```
$('.buttonclass').click(function () {
    var id = "";
    var oTable = $("#users").DataTable();
    $(".groupCheckBox:checked", oTable.fnGetNodes()).each(function () {
        alert(id);
        if (id != "") {
            id = id + "," + $(this).val();
        } else {
            id = $(this).val();
        }
        document.getElementById("email").value = id;
    });
});
```

## error

```
Uncaught TypeError: oTable.fnGetNodes is not a function
```

please help

Comment: Use `$(<tableselector>).dataTable().fnGetNodes()` to use the legacy method on a DataTable 1.10.x API. There is a lot of identiclal questions addressing the issue, like this from the other day http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211119/datatables-1-6-vs-1-10-code-issues/41218639#41218639

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In DataTables v1.10 the function names have changed, compared to all versions since v1.9.

I guess you are looking for this method: https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().nodes()

**REFERENCE LINKS**

This is the legacy reference: http://legacy.datatables.net/ref

Since v1.10 the reference is here: https://datatables.net/reference/

Comment: something like that ? $(".groupCheckBox:checked", oTable.rows( '.groupCheckBox:checked' ).nodes().to$()).each(function () {

Comment: Not knowing the full context makes this hard to know what you want to achieve. Currently you are creating an ALERT for each row, probably for debugging purposes. My guess is that you iterate over each row which has a certain textbox checked, to get a value? Check out this API function, maybe this is of use for you: https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().every()

Comment: yes what i want is when button clicked. get the values of the checkboxes clicked. pls advice

Comment: Try it with this:  $(".groupCheckBox:checked", oTable.rows().every( function () {

Answer (score 4):

**Instead using** `DataTable()` **use this** `dataTable()`  **error will go away.**

```
$('.buttonclass').click(function () {
    var id = "";
    var oTable = $("#users").dataTable();
    $(".groupCheckBox:checked", oTable.fnGetNodes()).each(function () {
        alert(id);
        if (id != "") {
            id = id + "," + $(this).val();
        } else {
            id = $(this).val();
        }
        document.getElementById("email").value = id;
    });
});
```

Comment: I have the same issue. so will dataTable work with 1.10.13 as well in this case ? pls advice